# ExtJS - Add store to utility class

Tags: javascript, class, extjs, store

How should I use a store in a utility class in ExtJS 6.2.1?

In Grid components one can just do:

```js
Ext.define('App.MyGrid', {
   extend : 'Ext.grid.Grid',
   store  : 'myStore',
});
```

If I do this in my class:

```js
Ext.define('App.MyClass', {
   singleton : true,
   store     : 'myStore',
});
```

then `store` is just a string.

Comment: Which ExtJS version and framework do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```js
Ext.StoreManager.lookup(STORE_NAME)
```

Comment: Or `Ext.getStore('STOREID');` if you gave the store an storeId.